# Disable SQL Server Agent Job temporarily

Tags: sql-server

My SQL Server Agent job runs everyday 7 PM. How can I disable it to not run every 10th, 11th and 12th date of the month?

Now every month, On 9th, after completion of the job, I do manually by changing start date of the schedule to 13th. Is there any better approach get rid of this manual activity?

Comment: You may schedule jobs to disable and enable the job for you

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/121918/sql-server-agent-job-schedule-daily-except-1-day-per-month Please Check this link. Hope this helps you.